# How do I remove special characters from an extracted value of a query?

Tags: robotframework

I'm using the following code to get a user's recovery_token and store it in a variable:

```
Connect To Database         psycopg2     ${DB_NAME}                     
    ...                         ${DB_USER_NAME}
    ...                         ${DB_USER_PASSWORD}
    ...                         ${DB_HOST}
    ...                         ${DB_PORT}    
    ${RECOVERY_TOKEN}=          Query    select recovery_token FROM public."system_user" where document_number like '57136570514'
```

Looking at the log, the recovery_token is being saved as follows:

```
${RECOVERY_TOKEN} = [('eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6ImU3ZGM4MmNjLTliMGQtNDc3OC1hMzM0LWEyNjM4MDU1Mzk1MSIsImlhdCI6MTYyMzE5NjM4NSwiZXhwIjoxNjIzMTk2NDQ1fQ.mdsrQlgaWUol02tZO8dXlL3KEwY6kqwj5T7gfRDYVfU',)]
```

But I need what is saved in the variable ${RECOVERY_TOKEN} to be just the token, without the special characters [('',)]

```
${RECOVERY_TOKEN} = eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6ImU3ZGM4MmNjLTliMGQtNDc3OC1hMzM0LWEyNjM4MDU1Mzk1MSIsImlhdCI6MTYyMzE5NjM4NSwiZXhwIjoxNjIzMTk2NDQ1fQ.mdsrQlgaWUol02tZO8dXlL3KEwY6kqwj5T7gfRDYVfU
```

Is there any way I can remove the special characters?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The returned value is a list of tuples, a two-dimensional matrix (e.g. a table); if you have queried for 3 columns for example, the inner tuple would have 3 members. And if there were 5 records that match it, the list would have 5 tuples in it.

Thus to get the value you are after, get it from the matrix by its indexes (which are 0-based, e.g. the first element is with index "0"):

```
${RECOVERY_TOKEN}=    Set Variable    ${RECOVERY_TOKEN[0][0]}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply and the explanation.